# Create programatically a category on wordpress user sign up

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I need to create a category when a new user signs up. The category name should have the username when registering.

I tried editing wp-login.php and wp-signup.php with different codes. My last attempt was with:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php");
//Define the category
$category_fields = array('cat_name' => $user_name, 'category_description' => '', 'category_nicename' => $user_name, 'category_parent' => '');

// Create the category
$category_fields_id = wp_insert_category($category_fields);
```

at the end of wp-signup.php but still can't create a new category. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It might be better to write a plugin for wordpress. This way you can user [user_register hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) and don't have to worry about wordpress updates breaking your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook the user registration by adding your action

```
add_action('user_register', 'myfunc_registration');

function myfunc_registration($user_id) {

$user=    get_userdata( $userid );//get user info

$user_info->user_login;

$category_fields = array('cat_name' => $user_info->user_login, 
'category_description' => '', 
'category_nicename' => $user_info->user_login,
'category_parent' => ''
);

// Create the category
$category_fields_id = wp_insert_category($category_fields);

}
```

### [Plugin API/Action Reference/user register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

### [Function Reference/get userdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

> Also, keep in mind that validation of registration fields should not
>   be performed within this hook! Validate using the registration_errors
>   hook, instead (the user_register hook will not be called if
>   registration_errors validation fails).

Comment: And where should I put this code? is there any specific file and section for it?

Comment: In your functions.php

Comment: Ok, now the code is executed, but I get white screen after registration. The user is created, but it fails creating the category.

Comment: Now look up for how to create category